# Remote Upload from Direct Link

Tags: php, file-upload, remote-server

I have a big file with direct link from my server 1.

```
http://xx.com/linux1.iso (3 gb)
```

and i need upload to my second server with php (i dont have a good adsl and i have more big file, only 1 week for moving all website)

It is possible create a php script on server 2, copy the file with direct link from server 1 in to server 2?

Answer (score 0):

if you have ssh access to the one you want the file downloaded to login to a ssh session and use the link with `wget` to download the file (if the os on the server is linux)

to do it by php use `file_put_contents` with `file_get_contents`

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0); //makes it so script doesnt timeout after the default 30 seconds
//downloads the file then saves it to path
file_put_contents("/path/to/download/to/file.iso",file_get_contents("http://mylink.com/file.iso"));
```

the php script would obviously be put on the server that you want to download the file to

Answer (score 0):

Or if you're using SSH, then you don't need PHP. Just use the [SCP](http://www.hypexr.org/linux_scp_help.php) command.

```
scp your_username@server1:linux1.iso /some/local/directory/on/server2
```